# Haskell Eq between different types

Tags: haskell

I need to use this data structure `data D = C Int Float` and I need to compare it with an Int, for example `a::D == 2`.

How can I create an instance to define this kind of Eq ?

Thank you!

Comment: Note since I don't think you get a notification about this: I've edited my answer to add a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't; `==` has signature `a -> a -> Bool`, so it can't be used like this.

Using the [`convertible`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/convertible) package you can define

```
(~==) :: (Convertible a b, Eq b) => a -> b -> Bool
x ~== y = case safeConvert x of
            Right x' -> x' == y
            Left _ -> False

(==~) :: (Convertible b a, Eq a) => a -> b -> Bool
(==~) = flip (~==)

instance Convertible Int D where ... 
-- or D Int depending on what you have in mind
```

Without depending on `convertible`, you could just define a conversion function either from `Int` to `D` (and write `a == fromInt 2`) or vice versa.

A less recommended route (for this specific case I think it's simply worse than the first solution) would be to define your own type class, e.g.

```
class Eq' a b where
  (=~=) :: a -> b -> Bool

instance Eq a => Eq' a a where
  x =~= y = x == y

instance Eq' D Int where ...
```

etc.

Comment: I don't think that creating a custom class is a good advice. Especially to a newcomer.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov I already had a "more reasonably" alternative, but I've rewritten the answer to both add a better (IMO) solution and to put this one last.

Answer (score 7):

I would implement a projection:

```
getInt :: D -> Int
getInt (C i _) = i
```

and then compare with it:

```
getInt myD == 5
```

you can even include this into a record:

```
data D = C { getInt :: Int, getFloat :: Float }
```

if you like

Answer (score 1):

This *can* be done, but I doubt you will want to do this.  As Alexey mentioned the type of `(==)` is `Eq a=>a->a->Bool`, so the only way to make this work would be to make `2` have type `D`.  This may seem absurd at first, but in fact numbers can be made to have any type you want, as long as that type is an instance of `Num`

```
instance Num D where
    fromInteger x = C x 1.0
```

There are still many things to work out, though....

First, you need to fully implement all the functions in `Num`, including `(+)`, `(*)`, `abs`, `signum`, `fromInteger`, and `(negate | (-))`.

Ugh!

Second, you have that extra `Float` to fill in in fromInteger.  I chose the value `1.0` above, but that was arbitrary.

Third, you need to actually make `D` an instance of `Eq` also, to fill in the actual `(==)`.

```
instance Eq D where
    (C x _) == (C y _) = x == y
```

Note that this is also pretty arbitrary, as I needed to ignore the Float values to get `(==)` to do what you want it to.

Bottom line is, this would do what you want it to do, but at the cost of abusing the `Num` type, and the `Eq` type pretty badly....  The `Num` type should be reserved for things that you actually would think of as a number, and the `Eq` type should be reserved for a comparison of two full objects, each part included.